# Clicking on a menu cascade clicks on the canvas behind

Tags: python, events, canvas, tkinter, menu

I'm trying to do an image creator and editor in the style of Paint. In order to switch tool, save/open files and all that stuff, I created a menu with multiple cascades.
I have bound the canvas to a function via a mouseclick event, and now, when I click on a menu cascade command over the canvas, then the function is called.

So, basically, I try to use the menu bar and it clicks on the canvas, which I don't want to happen. Any idea of how I could stop it?

Comment: show your code - or better minimal version with the same problem.

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve